# Sum() mysql, suma de

Tags: mysql

gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

tengo dos tablas tabla1 y tabla2.

Hago un select normal en tabla1, pero aprovecho y cuento unos registros de mi tabla2. Hasta ahi, todo bien, me funciona y deuelve los registros.

pero necesito un tercer dato que es sumar los dos registros anteriores.

Tengo hasta ahora, funcionando:

```
select nombre, apellido, direccion,
 (select count(*) from tabla2 where codigo= 1 and nombretable2= nombre) as cantidad,
 (select count(*) from tabla2 where codigo2= 2 and nombretable2 = nombre) as cantidad2,

from table1
where año = "**parametro**";
```

y necesito sumar  (cantidad+cantidad2) as cantidad3.

pero cuando hago:

```
select nombre, apellido, direccion,
     (select count(*) from tabla2 where codigo= 1 and nombretable2= nombre) as cantidad,
     (select count(*) from tabla2 where codigo2= 2 and nombretable2 = nombre) as cantidad2,
     sum(cantidad+cantidad2) as cantidad2,
    
    from table1
    where año = "**parametro**";
```

ya no me funciona, que puedo estar haciendo mal?

esto lo estoy haciendo en laravel, ya que con eloquent no supe hacerlo, lo estoy haciendo con raw: osea, como si una consula mysql nativa fuera.

Comment: Hola, podrias decir si alguna de las respuestas dadas te fue util

Answer (score 1):

```
select nombre, apellido, direccion, (select ...),
(select ...), t.4 + t.5
from tabla t
where ...
```

Los campos que selecciones en la **cláusula select** tienen un orden, **1 = nombre**, **2 = apellido**, etcétera, lo que debes hacer es referirte a esos campos a través de su índice(ahora mismo no recuerdo si se empieza con el índice 0 o el 1), y a tu tabla le darías un alias yo le puse **t**.

Answer (score 1):

Aca te dejo un query que me parece puede funcionar, la verdad no se si es la mejor forma de plantear la consulta, pero en función de obtener el resultado de la suma de cantidad + cantidad2, debe funcionar.

Te recomiendo que antes de ejecutar esto dentro de laravel, lo hagas en cliente de base de datos, tipo phpmyadmin o pgadmin si usas mysql o postgres respectivamente.

```
SELECT nombre, apellido, direccion, cantidad, cantidad2, (cantidad + cantidad2) AS total_cantidad
FROM (

select nombre, apellido, direccion,
     (select count(*) from tabla2 where codigo= 1 and nombretable2= nombre) as cantidad,
     (select count(*) from tabla2 where codigo2= 2 and nombretable2 = nombre) as cantidad2,
     sum(cantidad+cantidad2) as cantidad2
    
    from table1
    where año = "**parametro**"
) AS tabla_z
```